# Abstract Vector Space: Distance and Angle

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I saw the following example of an abstract vector space: $V$ is the vector space made up of vectors of the form $(a, b)$ with $a+b=1$. The way we add and scale vectors in $V$ is:
$$(a_1, b_1) + (a_2, b_2)=(a_1+a_2-1, b_1 + b_2)$$
$$c(a, b)=(ac-c+1,bc)$$
It's easy to check this is indeed a vector space with $(1,0)$ acting as the zero vector.

And I know we can use the inner product to define the concept of distance and angle by saying the norm of a vector is $||\vec{v}||=\sqrt{\vec{v}  \cdot \vec{v}}$, the distance between two vectors is $||\vec{v}-\vec{w}||$ and the angle between two vectors is $\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}}{||\vec{v}||||\vec{w}||}\right)$. Are these calculations only for $\mathbb{R}^n$ or are they fine for abstract spaces as well? Because I was trying a few random calculations and came up with:

$(2,-1)$ and $(10,-9)$ are in $V$ with the distance between them being $$||(2, -1)-(10,-9)||$$$$=||(2,-1)+-(10,-9)||$$$$=||(2,-1)+(-8,9)||$$$$=||(-7, 8)||$$$$=\sqrt{(-7,8) \cdot (-7, 8)}$$$$=\sqrt{49+64}$$$$=\sqrt{113}$$

And the angle between them being $$\arccos\left( \frac{(2,-1)\cdot(10,-9)}{||(2,-1)||||(10,-9)||}\right)$$$$=\arccos\left(\frac{29}{\sqrt{(2,-1)\cdot(2,-1)}\sqrt{(10,-9)\cdot(10,-9)}}\right)$$$$=\arccos\left(\frac{29}{\sqrt{5}\sqrt{181}}\right)$$$$\approx 15.42^{\circ}$$

But clearly this vector space $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's a straight line through the origin (since $a+b=1$). So I would think the angle between all these vectors is $0^{\circ}$ or $180^{\circ}$. Am I applying the calculations correctly? Or is this just how these measurements work in different spaces?

Comment: $V$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$. It is a **subset** of $\Bbb{R}^2$ which happens to be a vector space under **different** operations. A subspace is a subset that is a vector space under the **same** operations inherited from its parent space. Similarly, the usual dot/inner product on $\Bbb{R}^2$ will not be an inner product on $V$; in particular it won't be linear in the first coordinate with respect to the special addition/scalar multiplication operations on $V$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the clarification on Subspace vs subset and how  V did not have the same operations as R^2 and thus we'd need to create a new inner product operation for V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the traditional definition of the length of an ordered pair in this context because that length does not interact properly with the vector space operations. In particular,
$$
||2v|| \ne 2 ||v||.
$$

Whenever you have an inner product that does play nicely with vector arithmetic in an abstract vector space you can use it to define angles in that vector space. You can even have different inner products on the same space. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the inner product
$$
\langle (a,b), (c,d) \rangle = ac + 2bd
$$
leads to different lengths and angles.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'll try to think of a new inner product operation and use that to calculate the distance and angle!

Comment: @ruferd Before you look for an inner product I suggest you work out the dimension of that vector space. Can you find a basis?

Comment: I know it's 1-dimensional because it can be written as the span of any vector in it, say (2, -1) for example. Does the fact that it's 1D mean we can't find an inner product for it?

Comment: For a one dimensional space you can pick any nonzero vector $v$ as a basis. Then every other vector is a scalar multiple of $v$ and you can define the inner product of any two vectors as the product of those scalars. Then the angle between any two vectors will be $0$ or $\pi$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, thank you for the insights!